# Combine a name/value table (enumeration, properties) into one row in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

We have a number of tables that are properties or enumerations, where it would be convenient to convert this into a single row where the column name is the name and the value is the value in the following table:

```
thedb=> select * from nv_props;
 id |       name       |      value       
----+------------------+------------------
  2 | Serial Number    | 01234567
  3 | Part             | 2KEWL4U
  4 | Model            | CustomersTest
  1 | Firmware         | .03-b
```

Like a transpose of the name value pairs

```
 Serial Number    | Serial Number    | Serial Number    | Firmware
------------------+------------------+------------------+------------
 01234567         | 2KEWL4U          | CustomersTest    |.03-b
```

The names have a unique constraint, couldn't find a simple solution.

Thanks,
MJ

Comment: You are attempting to `pivot` your results.  If you know the number of potential columns, then it's pretty straight-forward (lots of examples on SO).  If you don't, then you're looking at using `dynamic sql`.  Just search around.

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't find a simple solution perhaps you weren't aware of a generic approach to a "pivot" using conditional aggregates (case expressions) in a group by query.

```
select 
       min(id) as gid
     , max(case when name = 'Serial Number' then value end) as col1
     , max(case when name = 'Part'          then value end) as col2
     , max(case when name = 'Model'         then value end) as col3
     , max(case when name = 'Firmware'      then value end) as col4
from nv_props
where id in (1,2,3,4)
```

You can (re)name the columns as you see fit.

What you haven't supplied in the sample data is a "column in common" across the 4 rows which is what one would normally group by. I trust you can apply this example to your specific situation.